# Android animation while switching imageview resource

Tags: android, image, animation, resources, screen

Well this is the code I use to animate the view so that old image disappears (black background) and new one slides in from outside (from left to right).

```
this.imgView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right));

this.imgView.setImageResource(imageArray[next]);
```

How do I make it that old image slides out of the screen before new one shows up. Would be great if both were visible but I guess that would require 2 views to switch, so for now I could stick to one on screen at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewFlipper to switch between two ImageView:s in the same Activity and set a slide animation to the ViewFlipper.

Set correct image resource in the next and previous image view before calling showNext() and showPrevious().

Comment: That would help only when the animation is after user action, right? It's a 2-direction scroll. I will not know if user wants to scroll forward or backward untill he actually drags finger on screen. So user finished "fling" > app loads the other view with pic and animation depending on fling/swipe/drag direction  ?

Comment: Yes, the user would have to finish the "fling/swipe/drag" before you can call showNext() or showPrevious().

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using TranslateAnimation.
apply the following code and see what happend

```
  TranslateAnimation left = new TranslateAnimation(-480, 10, 0, 10);
  left.setDuration(2000);

  left.setRepeatCount( 1 );
  view=(ImageView)findViewById( R.id.iv);
  view.startAnimation(left);
```

Create your own TranslateAnimation and apply accordingly