# Android swapping two images with animation

Tags: android, image, swap

Firstly sorry about my grammar.

I have two `ImageViews` and I want to swap the images with each other. I know that I can use `setImageDrawable` or `setImageBitmap` methods to change the images, but it's not exactly what I want. What I want is the images should change their places with each other. I mean with a slide animation.

What should I do ? Can I continue to use an `ImageView`?

For example I have a puzzle 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/15-puzzle.svg/220px-15-puzzle.svg.png

Imagine that there is 16 in the empty area and i want to swap 12 with 16 .

Comment: Your grammar is just fine! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

> ### [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#tween-animation)
>
> The Android framework APIs provides a set of 2D-drawing APIs that allow you to render your own custom graphics onto a canvas or to modify existing Views to customize their look and feel. When drawing 2D graphics, you'll typically do so in one of two ways:
>
> 1. Draw your graphics or animations into a View object from your layout. In this manner, the drawing of your graphics is handled by the system's normal View hierarchy drawing process — you simply define the graphics to go inside the View.
> 2. Draw your graphics directly to a Canvas. This way, you personally call the appropriate class's [`onDraw()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method (passing it your Canvas), or one of the Canvas `draw...()` methods (like [`drawPicture()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPicture(android.graphics.Picture,%20android.graphics.Rect))). In doing so, you are also in control of any animation.

Comment: That seems to be the answer but I was afraid of using canvas. However, I do have to learn it . Thanks so much for your answer

Answer (score 2):

If based on a gesture the user is going to do, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689220/android-animation-while-switching-imageview-resource) could help you.

For working with animations, [this tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343) can help, and you'll be focusing on using the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). This will work for all kinds of components or even layouts.

Also, I found [this link](http://androidworkz.com/2010/07/06/source-code-imageview-flipper-sd-card-scanner/) that demonstrates using a ViewFlipper with ImageViews and slide animations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks dude but rather than one view, I have two views and I want to change the places of the images. By the way, thank for the compliment about my grammar  , I'm trying to be careful :)

Comment: Hey no problem. Glad to try and help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Button and then apply animation.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:text="Button 1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="45dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:text="Button 2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="45dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn3"
android:text="Button 3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn4"
android:text="Button 4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.animation.Animation;
  import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class LayoutMargingActivity extends Activity 
  {
Button b1, b2, b3, b4;

TranslateAnimation left, right;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    left = new TranslateAnimation(-480, 10, 0, 10);
    right= new TranslateAnimation( 480, 10, 0, 10);

    left.setDuration(2000);
    right.setDuration(2000);

    left.setRepeatCount( 1 );
    right.setRepeatCount( 1 );

    b1 =(Button)findViewById( R.id.btn1);
    b2 =(Button)findViewById( R.id.btn2);
    b3 =(Button)findViewById( R.id.btn3);
    b4 =(Button)findViewById( R.id.btn4);

    b1.startAnimation(left);
    b2.startAnimation(right);
    b3.startAnimation(left);
    b4.startAnimation(right);
}
}
```

I think this will help you.